# Django circular dependency

Tags: python, django

I'm getting the error `django.db.migrations.graph.CircularDependencyError` when applying migrations. It's noticeable that I'm starting with an empty database.

I also managed to boil down to the class that is causing the error, which seems to be `OAuthAccessToken`.

```
class OAuthAccessToken(Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='oauth_access_tokens',
        help_text=_('User'))

    provider = models.ForeignKey(Provider, related_name='oauth_access_tokens',
        help_text=_('OAuth provider'))

    token = fields.SafeRandomField(max_length=32,
        help_text=_('Access token'))
```

The code above only works if I comment the `provider` declaration. The `Provider` class is from the allaccess framework. Here's its declaration:

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Provider(models.Model):
    "Configuration for OAuth provider."

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    request_token_url = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=255)
    authorization_url = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    access_token_url = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    profile_url = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    consumer_key = EncryptedField(blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    consumer_secret = EncryptedField(blank=True, null=True, default=None)
```

One other way for me to make the code work is if I remove `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'api.User'` from my settings file, in which case the first code sample works.

The thing is, I inspected the migrations and found this:

```
    migrations.CreateModel(
        name='OAuthAccessToken',
        fields=[
            ('uid', rest.fields.IDField(default=rest.fields.GenerateID(15, b'0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'), max_length=15, serialize=False, primary_key=True, help_text='Server generated public unique ID')),
            ('creation_date', models.DateTimeField(help_text='Creation date', auto_now_add=True)),
            ('last_update', models.DateTimeField(help_text='Last update', auto_now=True)),
            ('token', rest.fields.SafeRandomField(default=rest.fields.GenerateID(32, b'0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'), help_text='Access token', max_length=32)),
            ('provider', models.ForeignKey(related_name='oauth_access_tokens', to='allaccess.Provider', help_text='OAuth provider')),
            ('user', models.OneToOneField(related_name='oauth_access_tokens', to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, help_text='User')),
        ],
        options={
            'abstract': False,
        },
        bases=(models.Model,),
    ),
```

But I'm failing to see where the circular dependency is.

Edit:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 338, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 106, in handle
    plan = executor.migration_plan(targets)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 49, in migration_plan
    for migration in self.loader.graph.forwards_plan(target):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/graph.py", line 55, in forwards_plan
    return self.dfs(node, lambda x: self.dependencies.get(x, set()))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/graph.py", line 105, in dfs
    raise CircularDependencyError()
django.db.migrations.graph.CircularDependencyError
```

Edit: update using django 1.7.7

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 338, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 106, in handle
    plan = executor.migration_plan(targets)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 54, in migration_plan
    for migration in self.loader.graph.forwards_plan(target):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/graph.py", line 60, in forwards_plan
    return self.dfs(node, lambda x: self.dependencies.get(x, set()))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/graph.py", line 124, in dfs
    self.ensure_not_cyclic(start, get_children)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/graph.py", line 112, in ensure_not_cyclic
    raise CircularDependencyError(", ".join("%s.%s" % n for n in cycle))
django.db.migrations.graph.CircularDependencyError: api.0001_initial, allaccess.0001_initial
```

Comment: Can you post the full error message? More information on your migrations would be helpful too, particularly on the dependencies.

Comment: @mu無 On different models, though, so that's no problem.

Comment: @mu無 I already tried a different name, no effect

Comment: @knbk please see the edit! I failed to spot any interesting details, but please give it a go =\

Comment: Can you upgrade to the latest 1.7 update and post the new error message?

Comment: I'm using 1.7.1, you mean I should update to 1.8 ?

Comment: No, just 1.7.7. Minor updates (1.7.x) include security patches and important bugfixes, you should always install those.

Comment: Updated. I think I get the dependency error now. The dependency is on the migration, not the model itself, it seems

Comment: Can you try to remove and recreate your migrations? I believe circular dependency handling has improved since 1.7.1, so that alone might fix it.

Comment: I'm using a script which always clears all migrations and then generates them again, so it always starts from scratch

Comment: I think I know how to solve, but it will require some refactoring. I think I need to put the User model in some other migration to remove the dependency. I'll try and let you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens that I needed to refactor the code and create a new app to contain some of the models to solve this issue. Django then creates several migrations (like 0002, 0003) and is therefore able of resolving the circular dependency.